# Calculating Determinant Using an Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$detA_{6x6} \neq 0$.

$2A+7B=0$

Calculate $6det(2(A^t)^2B^{-1}A^{-1})$

My solution attempt:

$A = -7/2*B$ and $det A^t = det A$ so $6det(2*A*(-7/2B)*B^{-1}A^{-1}) = 6det(-7)= 6*(-7)^6 = 705894$

This seems to be incorrect but I can't find why. I would greatly appreciate if someone could point out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$6det(2(A^T)^2B^{-1}A^{-1})$

$=6det(2(A^T)^2)det(B^{-1})det(A^{-1})=$

$=6 \cdot 2^6 det(A)^2 det(B)^{-1} det(A)^{-1}=$

$= 6 \cdot 2^6 det(A) det(B)^{-1} = $

$= 6 \cdot 2^6 det(A) det(-\frac{2}{7}A)^{-1} = $

$= 6 \cdot 2^6 det(A) \cdot (-\frac{2}{7})^{-6} \cdot det(A)^{-1} =$

$= 6 \cdot 2^6 \cdot \frac{7^6}{2^6}=$

$= 6 \cdot 7^6=$

$=705894$

So your answer is right, but I see that you want to do the calculations very quickly and you might lose yourself in the process ;-)